# How to use Masquerade in Django 1.11+

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-1.11

Masquerade option is no longer supported in Django 1.11 , so what is the alternative to it ?

Any known fix available for it ?

Comment: The inital error that I am getting is in : request.user.is_masked ...'User' object has no attribute 'is_masked'

Comment: The mask_on.send is not switching the user like before.